# Pegar somente o valor e formatar em 2 casas decimais

Tags: sql, python, sql-server, postgresql

Bem, 
tenho um script em python que consulta duas bases diferentes para verificar valores por dia, umas em SQLSERVER e outra em Postgres.

Usei um if para avisar se os valores eram diferentes e se for, avisar.

O que acontece e que estava alarmando mesmo eu consultando na base que eram iguais.

Ao printar o resultado das variaveis do script me deparei com isso
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como obtenho somente o valor, sem a informação de decimal e dos caracteres e o formato para somente 2 casas decimais?

Comment: Essas duas linhas que postou que foram comparadas entre si? Percebeu que a primeira é uma lista e a segunda uma tupla? Não poderia ser esse o problema?

Comment: E se é pra comparar, e o dado for interpretado como float, não se usa igualdade, e sim `valor-absoluto(a-b) < 0.0000...0001` (precisão aceitavel), ou simplesmente pega os dados como inteiros. (se bem que, olhando a classe Decimal, provavelmente seu erro é no if e não tem nada a ver com o que foi descrito na pergunta)

Comment: Sobre o comentário do Bacco, existe [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) que pode ser utilizado para tal finalidade.

Comment: Da forma como está, não temos dados suficientes para ajudar. Clique em [edit] e poste o código da comparação pra gente entender o problema e o output completo do seu debug em texto, não em imagem, para que a comunidade possa ajudar mais objetivamente.

Answer (score 1):

```
cast(seu_campo AS NUMERIC(15, 2))
```

Comment: Lembrando que no lugar do 15 você adapta ao tamanho que precisar.